# JPA query with filter on current time stamp - seconds for Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, function, datetime, jpa

I am using JPA, Eclipse link, Oracle.
I am trying to introduce a condition in my JPA query equivalent to following oracle expression

```
current_timestamp - NUMTODSINTERVAL(10, 'SECOND')
```

I have tried several queries similar to following

```
select u from User u where (current_timestamp - FUNC('NUMTODSINTERVAL', :offset, 'SECOND')) > u.birth_date
```

but to no avail. All result in syntax errors. I want to avoid native query as well as calculating values using java.
I found following on some oracle website.

> Use the add_months function in Oracle, and use simple math to convert the month value to seconds.

If above is possible then I'll be able to use following

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select u"
                    + " from User u"
                    + " where"
                    + " FUNC('add_months', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, :offset) > u.birth_date "//)"// 
                    );
    query.setParameter("offset", getOffSet());
```

Edit: I need some Eclipse link JPA way of doing this or Oracle way using which add_months can be used to add/deduct seconds.

Comment: Please include the error message, the SQL that was generated, and the SQL that you want (and try the SQL you want to ensure it actually works)

Answer (score 1):

(Standard JPA 2.1) JPQL allows "FUNCTION" to be included in WHERE clauses. Nowhere is there a "FUNC", except maybe in some vendor extension, and people are always advised to avoid those particularly where there is a standard

Comment: Thanks for the advice, will keep in mind. I am still looking for the solution to my original issue.